# Way to Add data in Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, logic

I am creating a Java App, and using firestore as the database, I intent to add data to the Firestore when user click on "Join Btn". All variable is already defined in model class. The problem now is when I click the Join Btn, the data is not stored in Firestore. I am not sure why does this happen.

Below shows the model class and addedToJoined function.

```
private String eventName;
private String eventDate;
private String eventVenue;
private String eventDesc;
private String eventDocId;

private void addedToJoined(){

    final HashMap<String, Object> joinedMap = new HashMap<>();

    joinedMap.put("eventName", event.getEventName());
    joinedMap.put("eventDate", event.getEventDate());
    joinedMap.put("eventVenue", event.getEventVenue());
    joinedMap.put("eventDesc", event.getEventDesc());

    final HashMap<String, Object> participant = new HashMap<>();

    participant.put("eventName", event.getEventName());
    participant.put("participated_users_name", fAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());



    fStore.collection("CurrentUser").document(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .collection("MyFavourite").add(joinedMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
            Toast.makeText(EventDetail.this, "Event saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });

    fStore.collection("EventDetail").document(event.getEventDocId()).collection("event").add(participant).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
            Toast.makeText(EventDetail.this, "Event added to record.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens inf the Task is not successful? Is your onComplete event triggered?

Comment: posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  implementing the code with the help  of public [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#add_data) in which the whole description of storing data into Firestore has been provided with the help of onSuccess and onFailure listeners and the [video](https://youtu.be/kDZYIhNkQoM?t=394) in which it has been explained along with using the onComplete Listener at 06:36.if the problem persist kindly share any error message you are getting.